# Passing command line arguments to app written in C

Tags: c

Here I wrote a little app which is able to read command line arguments

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "Il:o:vh?")) != -1) 
    {
        switch(c)
        {
            case 'I':
                printf("I");
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

The problem is that when I try to compile it the compiler prints

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘getopt’ from incompatible pointer type
```

and program crash.
What I miss ?

Comment: How exactly does it crash? What's the command, what's the error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `argv` argument to `main` should have type `char *[]`, not `const char *[]` so that it can be converted to the `char *const []` that [`getopt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) expects. In fact, `char *[]` or equivalent is mandated by the C standard for hosted implementations.

Comment: Why would that make the program crash, though?

Comment: @Rup: I must admit that that's a mystery to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
```

should be

```
//no const
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
```